# CNN: ValueError : Error when checking input: expected conv2d_48_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28333, 3)

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I know that this has been asked before, but none of the solutions are working on my program.
Here is the scenario:
I am trying to re-implment a project. I have 3500+ images and a csbv that has imageName, CameraId and Temperature.
I need to predict the probability of the temperature from those images.
The images are in a 'dataset' folder and name of subfolders are CameraID
One-Hot Encoding is used for Labeling wherein, "dimension that represents correct temperature will be 1"
I used an Identity matrix for this.

After loading the images into an image_array, I put them in an *Xarr* that contains the image(in pix), imagename and cameraId. Y is out the output.

When I feed into CNN, my input shape is (640,480,3), but I keep getting an error:

> ValueError : Error when checking input: expected conv2d_48_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28333, 3)

I tried to use the solution to reshape, but it keeps saying

> list do not have an attribute of reshape

I tried to use np.array() and np.asarray(), but there is no work.

Can anyone help me?
Also, I just want to confirm, when I transform an image to pixel, I still need to label so I need to put them together in an array, right or no?

Model: "sequential_12"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 213, 160, 32)      896

---

batch_normalization_60 (Batc (None, 213, 160, 32)      128

---

conv2d_49 (Conv2D)           (None, 71, 53, 32)        9248

---

batch_normalization_61 (Batc (None, 71, 53, 32)        128

---

max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 35, 26, 32)        0

---

dropout_36 (Dropout)         (None, 35, 26, 32)        0

---

conv2d_50 (Conv2D)           (None, 11, 8, 64)         18496

---

batch_normalization_62 (Batc (None, 11, 8, 64)         256

---

conv2d_51 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 2, 64)          36928

---

batch_normalization_63 (Batc (None, 3, 2, 64)          256

---

max_pooling2d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 1, 64)          0

---

dropout_37 (Dropout)         (None, 1, 1, 64)          0

---

flatten_12 (Flatten)         (None, 64)                0

---

dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 512)               33280

---

batch_normalization_64 (Batc (None, 512)               2048

---

dropout_38 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0

---

## dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 70)                35910

Total params: 137,574
Trainable params: 136,166
Non-trainable params: 1,408

---

cnnLayer.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),

Comment: Are you trying to feed in a single image of size (640, 480, 3) ?

Comment: Yes. I was able to reshape it to (1, 640, 480,3), but I am having this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927184/maintain-array-length-after-ndarray-reshape?noredirect=1#comment104162061_58927184 .Do I need to resize the image?