# Maintain Array Length After ndarray.reshape

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I initially have an X_train size of (384, 640, 3) and a y_train size of (384,).
After I reshape X_Train to (1,384,640,3) the length of X_train became 1 and I am getting the ValueError shown below. Is there a way I can still have the length of X_train be 384 without reshaping it to a 3D array?

[image]

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 # Training the model
>   ----> 2 model.fit(np.array(xDataR), np.array(y_train), batch_size= 32, epochs=10)
>         3 # Problem:  Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 384 target
>   samples.
>         4 # Solution: train_data.size % batch_size = 0, or in other words the size of your data arrays needs to be a multiple of the batch
>   size.
>
> ~.conda\envs...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       727         workers=workers,
>   --> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       729 
>       730   def evaluate(self,
>
> ~.conda\envs...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, **kwargs)
>       222           validation_data=validation_data,
>       223           validation_steps=validation_steps,
>   --> 224           distribution_strategy=strategy)
>       225 
>       226       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)
>
> ~.conda\envs...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs,
>   sample_weights, class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split,
>   validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
>       545         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       546         workers=workers,
>   --> 547         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       548     val_adapter = None
>       549     if validation_data:
>
> ~.conda\envs...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _process_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights,
>   class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size,
>   workers, use_multiprocessing)
>       592         batch_size=batch_size,
>       593         check_steps=False,
>   --> 594         steps=steps)
>       595   adapter = adapter_cls(
>       596       x,
>
> ~.conda\envs...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
>   extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2532       # Check that all arrays
>   have the same length.    2533       if not
>   self._distribution_strategy:
>   -> 2534         training_utils.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)    2535         if self._is_graph_network and not
>   self.run_eagerly:    2536           # Additional checks to avoid users
>   mistakenly using improper loss fns.
>
> ~.conda\envs...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py
>   in check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
>       675                      'the same number of samples as target arrays. '
>       676                      'Found ' + str(list(set_x)[0]) + ' input samples '
>   --> 677                      'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
>       678   if len(set_w) > 1:
>       679     raise ValueError('All sample_weight arrays should have '
>
> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as
>   target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 384 target samples.

Comment: The first element of the shape of both X and y has to be the same number. What shape do you want for X? (384, 1, 640, 3) or what? Or maybe y has to be (1, 384) as well

Comment: After reshaping, my input is (1,384,480,3) and the length is 1.I would want my input to have length 384 and  y to just be (384,) to have length 384. I tried .swap() and .T, but it is not giving the length. I also tried to have make y (1, 384), but the CNN model gave an error.

Comment: What does your `X` constitute or? Is it 384 of 480 x 3 (black and white) images? Or is it 384 of 1 x 480 (RGB images - 3 channels)? It is not very clear what your X is. Depending on what X is the solution differs

Comment: x is 381X480x3 colored images

Comment: @eLg, can you update the question with the model you're using.

Comment: @thushv89 sorry for the late reply. I edited it